# ModelAttribute is not getting set after forcing a download

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, download

Adding an object to a ModelAndView in a Spring controller after forcing a download does not seem to work.

**Code at Controller method**

```
 ModelAndView view = new ModelAndView("");
 view.setViewName("pom-upload");
 view.addObject("uploadStatus", "Uploaded pom has been successfully processed!");
 response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=pom.xml");
 IOUtils.copy(inputStreamToDownload, response.getOutputStream());
 response.flushBuffer();
 return view;
```

I get the file downloaded successfully.
But when I try to access the "`uploadStatus`" message in my JSP like

```
<c:out value="${uploadStatus}"></c:out>
```

or

```
div id="status-message" class="alert alert-success" role="alert">${uploadStatus}</div>
```

I do not get the message from `${uploadStatus}`

What could the reason be and how would I fix this?

Comment: You can't return an HTML page AND a file download in the same response. Please explain what you're trying to accomplish and why.

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan I am just trying to show a success message on the page after the download.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, it sounds like you want to display a message to the user after they have downloaded a file. A couple options.

1. User clicks download link. This goes to success page. Success page uses Refresh header or javascript to initiate download. So success comes a little early.
2. See [Detect when browser receives file download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106377/detect-when-browser-receives-file-download) for some ideas on detecting when the browser gets the download.